# ¿Cómo cierra un Scanner en Java?

Tags: java

No entiendo cómo cierra el siguiente `Scanner`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion;

    while (!salir || !sc.hasNextInt()) {

        System.out.println("1. Opción 1");
        System.out.println("2. Opción 2");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");

        try {

            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Seleccionaste la opción 1");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Seleccionaste la opción 2");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Saliendo del programa...");
                    salir = true;
                    //sc.close(); IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 3");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("¡Error!... Debes insertar un número");
            sc.next();
        }
        //sc.close(); IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    }

    //Nunca entra aquí
    System.out.println("Cerrando sc...");
    sc.close();
}
```

- Si intento cerrarlo en el `case 3`, me tira el error: `IllegalStateException: Scanner closed`
- Si intento cerrarlo fuera del `try`, también me da el error `IllegalStateException: Scanner closed`
- Si intento cerrarlo fuera del `while` no entra nunca en esa parte.

**¿En qué momento pues cierra el `Scanner`, si nunca admite `sc.close()`?**

Comment: como comentario, si el programa espera opciones `1, 2 o 3`. Entonces no deberia aceptar *lineas* distintas a `"1", "2" o "3"`. Por ejemplo `"1 asd"` no deberia ser un input valido, por mas que el `sc.nextInt()` retorne 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas cerrando bien el `scanner`.

Los dos primeros errores `scanner closed` te están dando porque ya has cerrado el scanner y estas intentando leerlo en el `while`, por lo que te salta error y finaliza el programa.

El tercer error realmente no es un error, es la manera correcta. Pero el bucle `while` esta mal definido y esta esperando que metas otro número, en cuanto lo metes si que acaba el programa y llega a la parte en la que cierras correctamente el `scanner`.

Te recomiendo usar mejor un `do whille` y cambies la condición, para que muestre una vez el menú, lea la entrada del `scanner` y si `salir` es `true` salga del programa, y si no haga la comrpobación de `sc.hasNextInt()`.

Es decir, el bucle cambiarlo por esto:

```
do {
    ...
} while (!salir && sc.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es en qué momento se cierra, no puede ser en la tercera parte, porque nunca veo esto en pantalla: `System.out.println("Cerrando sc...");` aún poniéndolo de la forma que indicas.

Comment: ¿Lo has puesto con `&&` y `sc.hasNextInt()` sin la negación? A mi si me cierra así, y en tu código simplemente metiendo un numero más en consola también. Se cierra como lo estás haciendo, el problema está en el bucle.

Comment: Ahora sí, había puesto `sc.hasNextInt()` con la negación y por eso no funcionaba. Ahora sí muestra `Cerrando sc...`.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Seguí haciendo pruebas, pero no funciona bien del todo. Por ejemplo si escribo dos veces valores que no son números al principio, sale del programa la segunda vez. O sea, la 1ª vez sale el mensaje: `¡Error!... Debes insertar un número`, y si pongo otro valor no numérico, sale del programa.

Comment: Cierto, eso es por que en la condición del `while` no debería ser `hasNextInt()` sino `hasNext()`, ya que no esta devolviendo un número y finaliza el bucle por no cumplir la condición.

Comment: Correcto probé con `hasNext()`, pero no sé... el comportamiento es extraño. Por ejemplo: La 1ª vez me imprime: `¡Error!... Debes insertar un número` sin las opciones, la segunda vez me imprime las opciones y luego el mensaje `¡Error!... Debes insertar un número` y ya todas las veces que escribo un valor no numérico me muestra todas las opciones y el mensaje `¡Error!... Debes insertar un número`

Comment: Eso es porque la condición del `while`, que le esta diciendo que sea `salir` o que no haya algo mas en la entrada que leer. Realmente solo con poner `!salir` en la condición debería ser suficiente y resolver ese problema, ya que así no espera a que se tenga que leer nada mas.

Answer (score 1):

> El escanner se cierre siempre cuando ya no se usa.

En su código intente cerrar el escanner pero se usa el escanner para una lectura después de cerrarlo y por eso observe la excepción `IllegalStateException` (vea en la documentación [Scanner:next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), se describe cuando esta excepción puede surgir).

Lo más simple sería en mi opinion de cerrarlo al final del método, y no antes ya que corra riesgo de usar el escanner en el bucle después de cerrarlo.

Recomiendo utilizar un búfer leyendo del *standard input*. Eso no era la razón de la exepción pero es buena práctica.

También me gustaría simplificar su código. Espero que le ayuda a ser un poco más pragmatico:

- A menudo el `try/catch` no es una solución necesaria ni eficaz ni beneficiosa. Se usa en situaciones dificíl a controlar pero en este ejemplo es posible tener un poco más control así evitando un `try/catch`.
- Prefiero salir del bucle `while` cuando lo intento, es decir cuando pulso `3`. Me salió más simple el código así.
- Miro si hay un número en el *standard input*. Si hay, leerlo. Sino emitir que sólo se admiten las opciones mencionadas.
- Cuando se lee un número procesarlo.
- Utilizar un `if` en lugar de un `switch` porque es más fácil en un bucle (por el `break` en particular)

Espero que vea que el código sale más corto/preciso:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Recomendación: Usar un búfer, es buena práctica
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

        int opcion;
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            System.out.println("1. Opción 1");
            System.out.println("2. Opción 2");
            System.out.println("3. Salir");

            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                opcion = sc.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 3");
                sc.next();
                continue;
            }

            if (opcion == 1) {
                System.out.println("Seleccionaste la opción 1");
                continue;
            } else if (opcion == 2) {
                System.out.println("Seleccionaste la opción 2");
                continue;
            } else if (opcion == 3) {
                System.out.println("Saliendo del programa...");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Cerrando sc...");
        //Cerrar aquí porque seguro que el scanner ya no se usará más
        sc.close();
    }

}
```